# finding a basis vector in $\mathbb{R}^4$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, change-of-basis, gram-schmidt

I'm new to linear algebra and I'm having a hard time getting past this problem:

> given the basis vectors in $\Bbb{R}^4$
>
> $v^{(0)} = \begin{bmatrix} 0.5 \\ 0.5 \\ 0.5 \\ 0.5 \\ \end{bmatrix}, \\  
> v^{(1)} = \begin{bmatrix} 0.5 \\ 0.5 \\ -0.5 \\ -0.5 \\ \end{bmatrix}, \\
> v^{(2)} = \begin{bmatrix} 0.5 \\ -0.5 \\ 0.5 \\ -0.5 \\ \end{bmatrix}$
>
> which are mutually orthonormal, find a vector $v^{(3)}$ to form the complete basis $V = \{v^{(0)}, v^{(1)}, v^{(2)}, v^{(3)}\} $

In $\Bbb{R}^3$ I could use a cross product to find the third orthogonal vector, but in $\Bbb{R}^4$ I have no idea how to approach this.  I think the vector should be something like this:

> $v^{(3)} = \begin{bmatrix} -0.5 \\ -0.5 \\ 0.5 \\ 0.5 \\ \end{bmatrix}$

I just don't know how to actually arrive at this mathematically.

Comment: I can already tell you it's not good since $v^{(3)} = -1 . v^{(1)}$.
There is intuition for this kind of thing but I strongly suggest you learn how to do this methodically so you don't have to rely on your "guts" when asked to do this. A good yet kind of lenghty way to build a orthonormal basis is the Gram-Schmidt method. Practice it, understand it, and you'll forever remember it =)

Comment: You should start looking for a vector that is linearly independent from ${ v^{(0)}, \dots, v^{(2)} }$. Then you can use Gram-Schmidt process (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gram%E2%80%93Schmidt_process)

Comment: Gram-Schmidt method!!  Thanks @Furrane.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, let's find a vector that is linearly independent form $ v^{(0)},v^{(1)},v^{(2)}$. You can easily check that $ u = (-1,1,1,1)^{T}$ satisfies this condition. In fact resolving the linear system $\alpha v^{0} +\beta v^{1} + \gamma v^{2} + \delta u = 0$ you'll find $\alpha = \beta = \gamma = \delta = 0$.

Then, in order to use Gram-Schimdt process, compute the scalar products with the orthonormal vectors you already have. In this case $u \cdot v^{(0)} = 1$ and $ u \cdot v^{(1)} = u \cdot v^{(2)} = -1$.

The vector defined by $ u-v^{(0)}+v^{(1)}+v^{(2)}$ in therefore orthogonal to $v^{(0)}, \dots ,v^{(2)}$ by construction and normalizing you get $v^{(3)} = \frac{1}{2}(-1,1,1,-1)^{T}$.

Comment: Solving the linear system, I got $ \delta = \alpha $ and $\beta = \gamma = -\alpha$, I noticed this is the same as the $v^{(3)}$ you have at the end.  Is it correct to assume that I didn't need the Gram-Schmidt process here since the given vectors were already orthonormal?

Comment: I think you made some mistake in resolving the system. Since vectors $v^{(0)}, \dots, v^{(2)},u$ are linearly independent the only solution is the trivial one. The sole purpose of the system is to prove that the vectors are l.i.
The specificity of this case (i.e. the "luck" we had choosing that specific $u$ over others $ w \notin Span(v^{(0)},\dots,v^{(2)})$) is that the final "normalization step" of Gram-Schmidt process is worthless since from the previous step we get a normalized vector (and this is not always the case as you can easily check)